# $G$ group $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ prove that $G/N\cong (\mathbb{R,+})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be the group of all the functions such that $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, Let define for all $t\in[0,1]$ that $(f+g)(t)=f(t)+g(t)$, I need to prove that $G/N\cong (\mathbb{R,+})$, such taht $N=\{f\in G|f(1)=0\}$

**My attempt:**

$f$ is homomorphism because $(f+g)(t)=f(t)+g(t)$

$Im(f)=\mathbb{R}$

Now all I need is to find $Ker(f)$, I think that $Ker(f)$ is $\{f\in G |f(a\in[0,1])=0\}$ but why it should be $Ker(f)=N$?

Comment: What is $N$ in your question?

Comment: $N=\{f\in G|f(1)=0\}$

Comment: You seem to have selected some homomorphism $f$, but you didn't write what it is. Also, consider $\varphi$ for its name instead of $f$ to avoid confusion with elements of the group.

Comment: What is the binary operation of $G$? composition?

Comment: What is the homomorphism being used here? Remember that the Kernel of the homomorphism should be $N$ and not $Ker(f)$

Comment: @hamidkamali: no, it's pointwise addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the homomorphism $\varphi: G\to \mathbb R$ given by $\varphi(f)=f(1)$. This is surjective and has as kernel $N$.
By the way, this shows also that $G/N \cong \mathbb R $ as vector spaces, as $\varphi $ is linear and hence $N$ is a subvector space.

Answer (score 1):

Let: $\varphi :G\to \mathbb R$ which: $\varphi (f)=f(1)$. $\varphi$ is homomorphism from $G$ to $(\mathbb R,+)$ and for every $r\in \mathbb R$, the constant function $f(x)=r$. Finally, $ker(\varphi)=N$.